# What kind of connotation does "make the most of it" have?

Tags: connotation

I am recieving a small scholarship for university, and I have been asked to write a couple sentences (presumably for the founders of the scholarship to see) describing what this scholarship means to me. I would like my last sentence to end with something like

> "...and I will make the most out of it."

I am afraid that this might sound like "this is a small amount of money, but I will do with it what I can."

Is my fear founded?

Comment: @JEL Thanks for the suggestion, I will use that. But just for me to understand; is there any room to interpret my original sentence in the way that I feared it might be interpreted?

Comment: I disagree with @NigelJ, I think the phrase `make the most out of it` is most often used in the case of a suboptimal situation, similar to `finding a silver-lining'.  But I agree with @JEL that if it's made explicit, the context overrides that default (and perhaps subjective) connotation.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the connotation of “make the most of it”

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/make-the-most-of) offer:

> To use to the best advantage.

Which would seem to suit your case, however the [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-the-most-of-something) definition reads:

> To use or enjoy something as much as possible.

Which does introduce the additional wording 'as possible' and thereby encompasses the concept of *less than* that you mentioned. Which is made even clearer in the example they offer:

> We’re only in Paris for a day, so let’s make the most of it.

*only* obviously implying a degree of *not enough*.

For a similar meaning, not open to a diminutive interpretation, I would suggest:

...and I will ***[make it count.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/make-something-count)***

> To make something have as useful and positive an effect as possible
>
> You only get one chance, so you have to make it count.

-Macmillan Dictionary.